# AngularJS Directive Template is not display

Tags: angularjs

I start learning AngularJS today with directive ... I can't get directive work. Please help

```
<html ng-app="ngBasic">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('ngBasic', []);
      app.controller('ngBasicCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.age = 20;
      });

      app.directive('myDirective', function($scope) {
        return {
          template: '<h1>{{age}}</h1>'
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ngBasicCtrl">
    <h1>{{age}}</h1>

    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <div my-directive></div>
    <div class='my-directive'></div>
  </body>


</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bigzidane/t8Lv3mpg/2/

Currently, the page onlys show 20. Expecting  tag but not displaying yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `scope` option to create an isolated scope the template can refer to :

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      age: '='
    },
    template: '<h1>{{age}}</h1>'
  }
});
```

Now you can pass the controller `$scope`'s `age` to the directive scope, for example this way :

```
<my-directive age="age+1"></my-directive>
```

Will render out `21`. Updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/t8Lv3mpg/3/**

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `$scope` from the function returning your directive as it does not take a `$scope` parameter.

```
 app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: '<h1>{{age}}</h1>'
    }
  });
```

Comment: ?? You can inject any service into a directive `app.directive('myDirective', function($location, $timeout, myService1, myService2) {` etc. But you cannot inject `$scope` since it is a `Scope` object and therefore has no provider.